# MFC ActiveX CShockwaveflash element. How to disable the context menu?

Tags: c++, flash, mfc, activex, contextmenu

So i'm using the ActiveX CShockwaveflash element in my MFC application and i want to disable the context menu.

I tried to process the ON_WM_CONTEXTMENU() message and overwrite the `OnContextMenu(CWnd* cWnd, CPoint point)` function. That didn't work.

Also i tried to sut up the hook for mouse events like this:

```
g_hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, &OnMouseEvent, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
```

Inside the OnMouseEvent() function i check the WPARAM. But only left mouse clicks are fired.

```
if ((nCode >= 0) && (wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN))
{
    // fires here on left mouse down
}
else if ((nCode >= 0) && (
    (wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN) || 
    (wParam == WM_RBUTTONUP) ||
    (wParam == WM_CONTEXTMENU)
)
{
    // never fires here
}
```

I also tried

```
m_flashPlayer.put_Menu(FALSE);
```

That hided some of the context menu items. But not all of them. Context menu still appears on right mouse down.

Answer (score 0):

The Shockwave ActiveX has a property named Menu. Set this to false and it should work.

Comment: I'm using CShockwaveflash1 class. There is no 'Menu' prorerty or something like that there. There is SetMenu(CMenu* pMenu) method. I tried to call it and pass NULL as the paremeter. That didn't help. Context menu still appears on right mouse down.

Comment: I don't know were you are looking for it. But the IShockwaveFlash interface has a property named Menu, as I told you. Use your Typelib Viewer and you can see it.

Comment: CShockwaveflash1 has one base type: CWnd. I didn't see IShockwaveFlash anywhere in Typelib Viewer...

Comment: You are just talking from the wrapper you got. I am talking from the ActiveX interfaces the control supports. Try to learn the difference ;)

Comment: Oh... i finnaly get it :) But i create my element with Create() method. For a specific reason i can't just add this element on my dialog through the Visual Studio dialog constructor.

Comment: The way you create the object isn't important. When you have one COM pointer you can query for the specific interface and set the Menu property to false...

Comment: I set this property to False and got the same effect as the *m_flashPlayer.put_Menu(FALSE);* That hided some of the context menu items. But not all of them.